# What is the best approach to append to a file in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I've been stuck with some simple task. Let's assume we have some pseudo code:

```
Enum.each 1..1_000_000, fn(id) ->
    some_complex_method(id) |> save_results
end
```

Where `save_results` is

```
def save_results(data) do
    {:ok, file} = File.open "data.log", [:append]
    Enum.each(data, &(IO.binwrite(file, &1)))
    File.close file
end
```

The thing is if our range is really big we are spending time on opening and closing the file. How to make it handle open state and call close method when work is done?

Comment: Your save_results code doesn't look like it would be opening and closing the file each time. What leads you to believe that's what's happening?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the important part in pseudo code. Now it's updated.

Comment: How about opening the file before your loop and closing it afterwards? It does not feel ideal but I'm sure it would work in your case. If you are willing to do a bit more work you can easily use a GenServer where you keep pushing the contents of your file write to. Then you make the GenServer write to file with a certain delay of let's say 10 messages. When 10 messages or a certain time interval are up you wite all messages to file together.

Comment: you may also want to create a "buf" via `StringIO` and write to it, like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72048883/3995261

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `:append` as write mode use `{:delayed_write, non_neg_integer, non_neg_integer}` in order for your writes to be buffered until a certain amount of data to write is reached or a certain amount of time is up. Don't forget to use `:append` additionally if you only intend to append at the end of the file!

The first `non_neg_integer` is the Size in Bytes to buffer before a write occurs.

The second `non_neg_integer` is the Delay in Milliseconds to buffer before a write occurs. For a more detailed explanation visit [the erlang documentation of `:file.open/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2).
For other possible modes check out the [elixir documentation for `File.open/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#open/2)

#### Your example could look like this:

```
Enum.each 1..1_000_000, fn(id) ->
    some_complex_method(id) |> save_results
end
```

Where `save_results` is

```
def save_results(data) do
    {:ok, file} = File.open "data.log", [:append, {:delayed_write, 100, 20}]
    Enum.each(data, &(IO.binwrite(file, &1)))
    File.close file
end
```

Whether this exact configuration is perfect for your case I cannot judge but it should definitely decrease the amount of File openings.

#### Translated the above configuration means:

Dear `File` module,
please buffer my writing to the file `data.log` until I asked you to write at least 100 Bytes of data or until you waited for 20 Milliseconds for me to give you more data to write.
Thank you very much!
Truly yours `your elixir coder`

Comment: Wow, you really have some humour !

Answer (score 2):

Can you do the work upfront and only once it's done do the file writing?

```
results = Enum.map 1..1_000_000, fn(id) ->
    some_complex_method(id)
end
```

and then:

```
log_results(results)
```

where:

```
defp log_results(results) do
    {:ok, file} = File.open("data.log", [:append])
    save_results(file, results)
    File.close(file)
end

defp save_results(file, []), do: :ok
defp save_results(file, [data|rest]) do
    IO.binwrite(file, data)
    save_results(file, rest)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Used the other answers to write a little appender function:

```
filewriter = fn (filename, data) -> 
  File.open(filename, [:append]) 
  |> elem(1) 
  |> IO.binwrite(data) 
end

filewriter.("Rakefile", "here's a line to append!\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look as if your code above will open and close the file on each write but if there's something that you're not showing then I'd suggest that perhaps you want to replace your `File.open/2` with [`File.stream!/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/File.html#stream!/3)

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the important part in pseudo code. Now it's updated. Basically we are going through 1...1_000_000, passing each number to some method, which generates some data and results of it is being saved in a log file.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve it? Maybe using GenServer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Path` module

```
Path.expand('./text.txt') |> Path.absname |> File.write("new content!", [:write])
# => :ok
```

Read more here 

[Working With the File System in Elixir](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-file-system-in-elixir--cms-28869)

Comment: This will not append data to the file, it will override its contents with "new content!"