# How to "inspect to file" (or to string) in Elixir?

Tags: debugging, elixir

In Elixir, we can `IO.inspect anyStructure` to get `anyStructure`'s internals printed to output. Is there a similar method to output it to a file (or, as a more flexible solution, to a string)?

I've looked through some articles on [debugging](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/debugging.html) and [io](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/io-and-the-file-system.html) but don't see a solution. I've also tried

```elixir
{:ok, file} = File.open("test.log", [:append, {:delayed_write, 100, 20}])
structure = %{ a: 1, b: 2 }
IO.binwrite(file, structure)
File.close file
```

but that results in

```
no function clause matching in IO.binwrite/2 [...]
def binwrite(device, iodata) when is_list(iodata) or is_binary(iodata)
```

I’ve also googled some "elixir serialize" and "elixir object to string", but haven't found anything useful (like `:erlang.term_to_binary` which returns, well, binary). Is there a simple way to get the same result that `IO.inspect` prints, into a file or a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already [`inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2) function (not the same as `IO.inspect`), just go with it:

```
#> inspect({1,2,3})
"{1, 2, 3}"

#> h inspect/2
                         def inspect(term, opts \\ [])

  @spec inspect(
          Inspect.t(),
          keyword()
        ) :: String.t()

Inspects the given argument according to the Inspect protocol. The second
argument is a keyword list with options to control inspection.
```

You can do whatever you wish with the string afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can give `IO.inspect` an additional param to tell it where to write to:

```
{:ok, pid} = StringIO.open("")
IO.inspect(pid, %{test: "data"}, label: "IO.inspect options work too \o/")
{:ok, {_in, out}} = StringIO.close(pid)

out # "IO.inspect options work too o/: %{test: \"data\"}\n"
```

It accepts a `pid` of a process to write to. `StringIO` provides such a process, returning you a string on close.

Comment: oh, this is quite a powerful approach, especially if it's possible to get `out` without closing `pid`, thanks

Comment: `StringIO.flush(pid)` can be used to get the output without closing the device

Answer (score 3):

> In Elixir, we can IO.inspect anyStructure to get anyStructure's internals printed to output.

This is not quite true; `IO.inspect` uses the [Inspect](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.html) protocol. What you see is not the internals of the struct, but whatever that struct's implementation of the Inspect protocol is written to produce. There are different options you can give to inspect, defined in [`Inspect.Opts`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html), one of them is `structs: false`, which will print structs as maps.

For example, inspecting a range struct:

```elixir
iex> inspect(1..10)
"1..10"
iex> inspect(1..10, structs: false)
"%{__struct__: Range, first: 1, last: 10, step: 1}"
```

To answer your question and to add to the other answers, here is a method that uses [`File.open!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#open!/3) to reuse an open file and log multiple inspect calls to the same file, then close the file:

```elixir
File.open!("test.log", [:write], fn file ->
  IO.inspect(file, %{ a: 1, b: 2 }, [])
  IO.inspect(file, "logging a string", [])
  IO.inspect(file, DateTime.utc_now!(), [])
  IO.inspect(file, DateTime.utc_now!(), structs: false)
end)
```

This produces the following `test.log` file:

```elixir
%{a: 1, b: 2}
"logging a string"
~U[2022-04-29 09:51:46.467338Z]
%{
  __struct__: DateTime,
  calendar: Calendar.ISO,
  day: 29,
  hour: 9,
  microsecond: {485474, 6},
  minute: 51,
  month: 4,
  second: 46,
  std_offset: 0,
  time_zone: "Etc/UTC",
  utc_offset: 0,
  year: 2022,
  zone_abbr: "UTC"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to combine [`inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2) which returns a binary *and* [`File.write/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#write/3) or any other function dumping to a file.

```elixir
File.write("test.log", inspect(%{a: 1, b: 2}, limit: :infinity))
```

Note the [`limit: :infinity`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html) option, without it the long structures will be truncated for better readability when inspecting to `stdout`.